# use purrr lambda in tryCatch

Tags: r, try-catch, purrr

I'd like to use `purrr`'s lambda `~`, if possible, instead of writing out `function(e)` in a tryCatch like the following:

```r
tryCatch(suppressWarnings(load("foo.R")),
         error = function(e) {
           foo <- "a"
           save(foo, file = "foo.R")
         })
```

I don't actually use `e` as an argument, and `~` is 10 characters shorter than `function(e)`. Simply swapping in `~` doesn't work, so I suspect I'm either misusing `~` , or `tryCatch` can't accomodate it.

```r
file.remove("foo.R")
#> [1] TRUE
tryCatch(suppressWarnings(load("foo.R")),
         error = ~ {
           foo <- "a"
           save(foo, file = "foo.R")
         })
#> Error in value[[3L]](cond): attempt to apply non-function
```

(I'm aware `file.exists` can be used instead of a `tryCatch` structure for this kind of thing, but as the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533552/load-a-data-file-in-r-using-trycatch) thread points out, there are other errors that could be thrown when trying to load a file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `as_mapper` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
file.remove("foo.R")
#[1] TRUE
tryCatch(suppressWarnings(load("foo.R")),
     error = as_mapper(~ {
       foo <- "a"
       save(foo, file = "foo.R")
     }))
list.files()
#[1] "foo.R"
```

Comment: I guess there's not a way to use `~` here without a wrapper? This ends up being just as long as writing out `function(e)`

Comment: @lost The `~` is optimized to use within the tidyverse functions. if you are using outside, then you need some wrapper